# Scala - Error type mismatch found : Any required: Array[Any]

Tags: scala

I am getting an below error while executing program....Does anyone help me with that which change I need to do it with recursion as I am new in scala?

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: Array[Any]
      array11(arr(acc),0)
```

Below is my code

```
object arr11 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    array11(Array(Array(1, 2, 11),0),0)
  }

  def array11(arr:Array[Any],acc:Int):Unit = {

    if(arr(acc).isInstanceOf[Array[Any]])
    {
      array11(arr(acc),0)
    }


  }
```

Comment: Hello Dhrumil, can you add a description of what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: Avoid `Any`! What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: If you are new to Scala, you shouldn't be using `Array` at all, and you shouldn't be using `Any`, either. In normal, ordinary Scala code `Array` and `Any` never appear. Put them off, learn them later.

Comment: I am try to implement code using tail recursion...and returning count of 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you do `if (x.isInstaceOf[X])`, the compiler still does not assume the type of `x` to be `X`, it is still the same as it was before the `if`. This is different in some languages, like Kotlin. In Scala if you want to do a thing like this, you use the pattern matching:

```
  def array11(arr:Array[Any],acc:Int):Unit = {
    arr(acc) match {
      case aa: Array[Any] =>
        array11(aa,0)
      case _ =>
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at function `array11`:

```scala
def array11(arr: Array[Any], acc: Int):Unit = {
  if(arr(acc).isInstanceOf[Array[Any]]) {
    array11(arr(acc),0)
  }
}
```

`array11` takes two arguments, first - `arr` should have type `Array[Any]`, but in line:

```scala
array11(arr(acc), 0)
```

`arr(acc)` will have type `Any` (because arr is `Array` of `Any`) and you are trying to pass an object of `Any` type as `Array[Any]` and the compiler shows you the error: `type mismatch`.
To make your code correct for compiler you should make cast `arr(acc)` to `Array[Any]` type, for example using `asInstanceOf`:

```scala
def array11(arr: Array[Any], acc: Int): Unit = {
  if(arr(acc).isInstanceOf[Array[Any]]) {
    array11(arr(acc).asInstanceOf[Array[Any]], 0)
  }
}
```

But your code has a very low type-safety in this case, you should get rid of using `Any` type in signatures as possible. Also using `asInstanceOf` - is a bad practice for the same reasons. I would advise you to refactor your `array11` function to make it more type-safe.